# How to save image directly and not through Dialogue box?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the image when I press Ctrl+s. But rather than directly saving the image it opens the "save as" dialogue box as shown in the image attached. I want my code to directly save it as tiger2.png when I press Ctrl+s.

```
   image = cv2.imread('tiger.jpg',0) #Reading the image

   cv2.imshow('image',image)
   k = cv2.waitKey(0)

   if k == 27:           #Closing window when user presses ESC key
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()

   elif k == 19:         #Saving image when user presses Ctrl+s

       cv2.imwrite('tiger2.png',image)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The problem is that CTRL+S is the built-in shortcut of the window created by `cv2.imshow`. If you want to use that shortcut, you'll need to implement your own GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that Ctrl + s is a built in function in cv2.imshow() which opens a save dialog: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5071

if you change

```
elif k == 19:
```

to something like

```
elif k == 115: #Save when pressing s
```

this will work as you intend.

Comment: Yes, it's mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563). However based on the code, it's now also implemented in the QT and Gtk backends as well, not just windows specific.

Answer (score 0):

When `cv2.waitKey(0)` is called, the computer waits for the next key to be pressed. `cv2.waitKey()` can not be used to detect two key presses at the same time.

You could try using `s` instead of `ctrl+s`.

```
   elif k == 115:    #Saving image when user presses 's'
       cv2.imwrite('tiger2.png',image)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: CTRL is a modifier, it won't be detected as an individual keypress by `waitKey`.

Comment: @DanMašek For me (Ubuntu 18, OpenCV 4, and Python 3), the CTRL key is detected as '227' by waitKey. The Windows Key (the key between CTRL and ALT on the left side of the keyboard) is the only key that is not detected as an individual keypress by waitKey.